# не выводится результат join

Tags: javascript

```
l1 = [2,4,3];


l1.reverse();
l1.join("");
console.log(l1);
```

выводится сам массив, результат join высветится только если console.log(l1.join(""));
хочу чтобы join работал не только после console.log() чтобы использовать результат.

Answer (score 1):

нужно было присвоить значение,

```
l1 = l1.join("");
```

Answer (score 0):

Для записи в память результата выполнения метода join создайте переменную или перезапишите l1:

```js
l1 = [2,4,3];
l1.reverse();
let str = l1.join("");
console.log(str);
```